# How to move all the elements in a list, a step forward in python?

Tags: python, list

if there is a list l=[1,2,3,4,5]
i want to insert an element in the beginning, and so all the elements should move a step forward and should result in an increase in the length of the list.\

How should I do this ?

Comment: `l.insert(0, value)`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to submit a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for your question!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.insert(i, x)`, where:

- `list` is the name of the list,
- `i` is the index of the element before which to insert, and
- `x` is the value to be inserted.

In your case, it should be:

```
l.insert(0,x)
```